# How to filter remove square bracket in json_query?

Tags: ansible, json-query

i have below json file and i am trying to filter the value but getting double square bracket but i want to remove the first square bracket using the regex_replace but dont how this works..
this  json file getting store in variable called config_params from there i trying to filter..

```
{
  "servers": {
    "server_details": [
      {
        "srv_make": "hp",
        "newip_address": "192.168.200.139",
        "newhostname": "hostbh1",
        "nic_macaddress": {
          "nic1-mac1_nic2-mac1": [
            "b8:83:03:81:4b:20",
            "b8:83:03:84:d5:1c"
          ],
          "nic1-mac2_nic2-mac2": [
            "b8:83:03:81:4b:20",
            "b8:83:03:84:d5:1c"
          ]
        },
        "vmotion_ip_address": "10.10.20.36",
        "iscsi_ip_address": "192.168.0.36",

      }
    ]
  }
}

mac_group_list: "{{ config_params | json_query('servers.server_details[*].nic_macaddress.nic1-mac1_nic2-mac1') }}"

        [
          [
            "b8:83:03:81:4b:20",
            "b8:83:03:84:d5:1c"
          ]
        ]
```

I am expecting the out put as below- how can i achieve this in json query.

```
  [
    "b8:83:03:81:4b:20",
    "b8:83:03:84:d5:1c"
  ]
```

Thanks

Comment: This sort of question is easier to answer if you show us what the input data looks like.

Comment: I think you have a typo in your data. Based on what you've posted here, your query is invalid, because `configuration_params` is a child of `Request`. I'm assuming it's supposed to be a sibling?

Comment: yes there issue in copy & paste now i have correct it..i think you may need to edit your answers based above updated file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is a list of lists, and you want the first element. You could simply ask for the first element, like this:

```
mac_group_list: >-
  {{ inputjson | json_query('servers.server_details[].nic_macaddress."nic1-mac1_nic2-mac1"')[0] }}"
```

Or you could use the `flatten` filter:

```
mac_group_list: >-
  {{ inputjson | json_query('servers.server_details[].nic_macaddress."nic1-mac1_nic2-mac1"') | flatten }}
```

You can also probably fix your query, but that's harder to answer without seeing what the original data looks like.

**Update**

Or you could write your query filter like this:

```
- set_fact:
    output: >-
      {{
        inputjson |
        json_query('servers.server_details[].nic_macaddress[]."nic1-mac1_nic2-mac1"[]')
      }}
```

I've reformatted it for readability, but that's effectively exactly what you have now with an extra `[]` at the end. Given your sample data -- fixed to meet the assumptions I described in a comment on your question -- this produces:

```
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "output": [
        "b8:83:03:81:4b:20",
        "b8:83:03:84:d5:1c"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I've updated this answer to match your sample data.